# Nim import typedef from C header file

Tags: ffi, nim-lang

I'm wondering if I can import a C type definition or if I need to redefine it in Nim?

Looking at program called `jhead` interfacing with this proc

`int ReadJpegFile(const char * FileName, ReadMode_t ReadMode);`

The second parameter ReadMode_t is an enum type in `jhead.h`

```
typedef enum {
    READ_METADATA = 1,
    READ_IMAGE = 2,
    READ_ALL = 3,
    READ_ANY = 5        // Don't abort on non-jpeg files.
}ReadMode_t;
```

Can I import this `ReadMode_t`? Or do I have to redfine it like below

```
type
  ReadMode_t* = enum
    READ_METADATA = 1, READ_IMAGE = 2, READ_ALL = 3, READ_ANY = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nim compiler needs to know about those C constants, so you have to define them to use them from Nim. However, this tedious copying can be simplified and even automated to some degree with tools like [c2nim](https://github.com/nim-lang/c2nim). In fact, if you take the following `test.h` file:

```
typedef enum {
    READ_METADATA = 1,
    READ_IMAGE = 2,
    READ_ALL = 3,
    READ_ANY = 5        // Don't abort on non-jpeg files.
}ReadMode_t;

int ReadJpegFile(const char * FileName, ReadMode_t ReadMode);
```

and run `c2nim test.h`, it will generate the following `test.nim` file for you, saving most of the tedious translation:

```
type
  ReadMode_t* = enum
    READ_METADATA = 1, READ_IMAGE = 2, READ_ALL = 3, READ_ANY = 5


proc ReadJpegFile*(FileName: cstring; ReadMode: ReadMode_t): cint
```